# Windows XP x64 virtual machine (VMWare ESX) using only 2 CPUs (out of 4)

Tags: windows-xp, vmware-esx, central-processing-unit, 64-bit

I just converted a physical Windows XP x64 machine with 4 CPUs to a VMWare virtual machine with 4CPUs (on a ESX server) using the VMWare Standalone Converter.

Everything worked just great, except that the OS now seems to use only 2 CPUs (when 4 are installed, see the following image). This must be a Windows XP issue rather than a VMWare issue, but I can not really rule out any reason at this stage.

[image: Device Manager vs. Task Manager]

What can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can also create one vCPU with 4 cores, check out: http://www.yellow-bricks.com/2009/06/04/per-processor-licenses-for-your-application/

Comment: That's a seriously good answer.

Comment: Thanks ! The original link is here: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1010184

Answer (score 4):

Are you using SP2? prior to that XP wouldn't support more than two CPUs. Even with SP2 XP will only support what it sees as two CPU sockets - so your third and fourth vCPUs would need to be seen by XP as cores of one or two CPUs.

Comment: Exactly so: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888732

Comment: You are right: it seems XP supports any number of cores it, but is limited in the number of processors. My physical machine had 2 dual core processors, thus 4 CPUs were seen.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that VMware guests can quite easily run more slowly with >1 vCPU, especially if the guest/core ratio is high, or the CPU load is high.  For example, a CPU instruction on a dual-CPU guest has to be queued by the hypervisor until two physical cores are available.  I've seen this effect in a production environment, where a P2V'd Oracle server guest, with 2 vCPUs runs more slowly than when running with 1 vCPU.  Just thought I'd pop that one in there.

Answer (score 0):

VMware has stated that a VM no longer is required to lock two CPUs to use the CPU if two CPUs are assigned to the VM.  The Vkernal is able to assign a single CPU and give it process time until both become avaliable.

Comment: I don't suppose you have a link to that statement?